# Power supply sequencing for low power camera module

Tags: power, power-sequencing

Could you please suggest a simple method how to make power on/off sequence of three different input voltages?

I'm making a board camera using this [image sensor](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtptm31azguj89f/Datasheet.pdf?dl=0).
The sensor requires three different input voltages: 3.3v, 1.8v and 1.2v. Also around the page 101 it says that there exists a power on/off sequence, which means the 1.2v should be applied first and 1.8v, 3.3v later. And the order should be reversed when the image sensor is turned off. But I have no idea how to make it.

Before taking account of the sequence, I planed to use TPS62243(3.3v->1.8v converter) and TPS62242(3.3v->1.2v converter) so that I have 3 different input voltages. (This is their [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps62242.pdf)) Could I use these voltage regulators for making the sequence? The data sheet says you could use EN pin for this. But I couldn't understand clearly how it works.

Or could you please suggest a way to make the power on/off sequence by adding a simple circuit? Because my application requires very small power consumption and price, I'm afraid of using a complex system for it. It would be very helpful, if you could give me suggestions.

Comment: You can't use one of the tools available online for power supply sequencing?

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't understand what you mean by the tools

Comment: I searched google for long time, but still couldn't find some IC for it.

Comment: What I think you need is a simple logic circuit or a micro controller  to sequence the 3 enable pins for the different supplies.

Comment: Ah... okay. I'm going to use a MCU board for controlling this camera. But it seems one mistake in programming would cause problem.. So I'd be happy if I could add some components in the camera board and make the sequence constantly.

Comment: One way, with no programming, would be to used power supply sequencing ICs. Lots of variations avalible depending on you requirements. Alternativly you can use the EN signal pins of the DC converters to turn them on, using the power rail on the first to pull high the enable signal on the next whos power rail pulls high the next enable signal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I'm searching for the ICs. And regarding the EN pin, would it also work for power off process?

Comment: Those EN pins are intended for switching on/off that regulator and their main use is to keep them off when power is off. Check in the datasheet that the power consumption in this mode (when disabled) is low enough for you. So YES, that is why these EN pins are there.

Comment: For sequencers, you could try one of the IPSPac series http://www.latticesemi.com/en/Support/PartNumberReferenceGuide/ispPAC.aspx , or perhaps one of the Analog devices parts http://www.analog.com/en/products/power-management/sequencing/digital-sequencers.html

Comment: The web page you link to is unavailable, so how much time is required between voltages during the ON sequencing, and how much time is required between voltages during the Off sequencing? [** Look here.**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ywndarhxsdde16o/Power%20supply%20sequencing.png?dl=0)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtptm31azguj89f/Datasheet.pdf?dl=0

Comment: I'm sorry that there the total time is specified as 200ms (the 3 voltages should rise and fall in 200ms). But the time for each voltage is from 0 to -. I'm really sory that I don't undrstand what this - means

Answer (score 1):

So, I got to the PDF link, and it is still loading after 10 minutes, so I'm not going to answer about your specific chip, since I'm currently in time that could be paid for. Pro tip for next time: If the PDF is slow, copy it to your own Dropbox/Google Drive/MS Cloud DriveThing and link from there.

You are feeding the sensor with 3.3V you say, so you cannot de-sequence without either an EN pin, or an energy buffer and power-fail detection on your camera board. The latter will make your camera board bigger, since I don't know the size or current consumption of your sensor, I cannot say how much it will influence your design. But most commonly you don't want that for a Sensor Board, since most people want them as small as possible.

So, you will need an EN pin anyway, since if you just turn off 3.3V to the board, the 3.3V will fall first: Bang, Wrong de-sequencing.

Which then makes me say, if you have one EN pin you need to handle correctly from the uC anyway, you might as well have 3. But, the easiest way would be either with sequence chips as such:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1Fd4z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then you can also make a simple power-fail detection, if you want:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBN7Km.png)</sup>

That's the least number of components I could think of, without using a Chip, since I'm out of time to also find you a chip, but there are Power Path and Power Failure chips out there, even very simple "Brownout Detectors" might work fine for you. But you will always need something like a diode in there, so you will need to really look very closely at your device's current usage profile and the diode drop that causes, to see if you can stay within the margins of the allowable power supply for 3.3V. A normal Schottky may work well enough if your supply is allowed to be within 3.1V to 3.5V, since I cannot think of a Schottky I recently used that had a larger forward-drop differential over a 2 decade current range. Or any diode I used, come to think of it, but it will depend on your main current set-point.

Again, all this would have been much more aimed had I been able to obtain the PDF in time.

Getting the power right, with a power-fail detection, is a lot easier if you use 5V in and buck-regulate all three voltages.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just changed the link to my dropbox file and then started reading your answer again